# Impossible to load data set[country_name] due to the following errors the paramerter has no value[par_country];

Tags: java, analytics, birt, spagobi, bi-tool

Step 1

I have created a Dataset which has parametric query

```
select city from country where country=$P{par_country}
```

I have added the attributes and on preivew it is working fine.

Step 2

Now i have created a LOV(List of values) with query

```
select cust_country from country
```

and on Testing it is giving me all the countries

Step 3

Added that LOV to AD(Analyical Drivers)

Step 4

Create a new cockpit with  Data source created and then select a pie chart and i am getting this error[image]

Comment: I am stuck in it from 2 days please reply if anyone has any answer on this

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the parameters at the "filters editor" (funnel icon) when you are edditing the cockpit. It shows a list with the parameters of the dataset, and you can set the default values, etc.

That's the theory... but my parameter's list its empty, so i can't do nothing with the dataset parameters...

Comment: thanks for reply and same in my case my parameter`s list is also empty.how to insert the parameters here any one...i have gone through this link also [https://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/4272.page] but adding that line also not helped.version i am using is 5.2

Answer (score 0):

After spending days on this finally this has worked for me

I have made the changes by follwing this link https://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/4272.page with some additional changes.

in below files:

1.SpagoBICockpitEngine/WebContent/js/src/ext4/sbi/cockpit/MainPanel.js

on first row function onShowFilterEditorWizard 
   *

```
config.stores = Sbi.storeManager.getStoreIds();
Sbi.trace("[MainPanel.onShowAssociationEditorWizard]: config.stores is equal to [" + Sbi.toSource(config.stores) + "]");
```

and uncomment the same lines in onShowFontEditorWizard method.

2.SpagoBICockpitEngine/js/src/ext4/sbi/widgets/grid/InMemoryPagingGridPanel.js

Row 96 in function loadStore, comment line as this:

```
//this.store.loadPage(1);
```

3. i have used javascript to add string parameter.

Query:`select country,cnt from country_duns PLACEHOLDER_COUNTRY`

and in edit scrpit

```
country = parameters.get('par_country');

if (country == null) {
  placeholder = " ";
}
else {
 placeholder = "where country = '" + country + "'";
}

query = query.replace("PLACEHOLDER_COUNTRY", placeholder);
```

parameter is ***par_country*** of string type